# Marketing Cloud - Does table exist

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm looking for a way, using SQL, to see if a table exists for any random given name

I've tried creating a simple "Select * from MyRandomTableName" but this doesn't work in Marketing Cloud as i need to map the columns from the table to the DE i'm writing it and i can't be sure of the columnnames.

Is there any way, using SQL or any other way thay can be automated, to check if a table exists? I don't want the actual data, i just want to check if it can execute so i know the table with the given name exists.

for testing reasons i've been using the MC interface. Activties -> SQL queries and i've tried to create a statement that it would accept.

Comment: Can describe with more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with the API, you'll have to do a retrieve of the target Data Extension first.  If you're inserting a SQL Query, you'll get an error if it doesn't exist.

You always have to create the Data Extension first.  The SQL Query activities do not originate Data Extensions.

Comment: I haven't used the API, only the website interface.

I have created 2 data extensions. Test1 ( with several randomly named columns ) and Test2 ( with a single column named "Name" ). I don't care about getting the actual data. I only want to check if the table exists. If i could do "Select * from X" and see if it can be executed i know the table exists.

Comment: What's the use-case?  It'd help to know why you need to know why a DE exists.